# summing elements of a list of csv lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list of csv lists like:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

What I want to do is sum each individual list i.e create a new list that is composed of each comma seperated variable summed, and check if they equal some value i.e:

check [0+0,0+2,1+1,2+0..... is equal to some number

I have gotten as far as:

```
 if sum(gcounter)==3:
   gamma=True
   print(gamma)
 else:
   pass
```

I have tried sum(int..., and tried using a for loop amongst others but it keeps throwing the same error each time i try a different method
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
So its a problem with the sum function

Trying to work this out has frankly left me feeling listless would greatly appreciate any help!!!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you really want here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
>>> lst = [[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
>>> print ([x for x in lst if sum(x) == 3])
[[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

Essentially I loop over `lst` getting one sublist at a time.  I sum the sublist and if it equals 3, I keep the sublist in the output list.

Comment: This is for 2.73 though right? I had to explicitly wrap `print` in parens to get this to work for 3.2

Comment: this throws the same error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: @HunterMcMillen -- Yes, on python3, `print` becomes a function.  I'll edit so it works on both.

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman -- Then your input list isn't in the format you think it is.  You have a sublist which contains another list.

Comment: @mgilson What other format could it be in? printing it to screen gives [[0,0], [0,2]... furthermore isinstance(list,list) is true

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman -- `isinstance(list,list)` can (almost) never be True because `isinstance` requires the first element to be an instance and the second to be a type.

Comment: isinstance(mynamedlist,list) returns at true value, sorry should have specified that

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman -- Sure, that's fine.  But what about every element in every sublist?  e.g. are you sure you don't have something like `[[1,2],[2,3],[4,[5,6]]]`  (The last element here will cause problems)

Comment: @jamylak -- Fair enough.  (I was wondering if there was any exception to that statement when I posted it ...).  But, in any event, I'm pretty sure that isn't the case here.

Comment: @mgilson, Yes, what I put in the original question is the entire list as it prints out, I'm doubtful it could be anything else (a tuple e.tc) as its in square brackets

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman -- I copy-pasted your data exactly and it works for me.  Also, this will work with tuples as well as lists.  Either you're missing something in your code that is changing the input, you're not using my idiom as it is presented here, or there's a problem with your python install (which is highly unlikely).

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman: What does `all(isinstance(el, list) for el in mynamedlist)` print for you? And `all(isinstance(subel, int) for el in mynamedlist for subel in el)`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Both of those print True

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman -- What do you get if you try `type(sum)`?  Perhaps you created your own sum function somewhere and are shadowing the builtin.

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman: Then mgilsons code should work just fine. Make sure you didn't get mixed up between variable names somewhere. Make sure `sum` is not rebound to another type.

Comment: @mgilson No sum is the built in one. ">>> type(sum)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>"

Comment: I'm getting a new error message:
"list indices must be integers, not list" Does this mean the individual elements i.e. [[i,o]] i and o are list? but they still sum when I do it direclty in the terminal i.e sum(mynamedlist[1]) returns the sum

Comment: @TariqRobinMuman -- we're not using indexing anywhere in this solution.  This problem *has* to be elsewhere.  Read the traceback very carefully.